# For which $u$ does the derivative $f'(u,0)$ of $f(x,y)=x^3/(x^2+y^2)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by setting**

**$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0 & (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$**
**(a) For which vectors $u\ne 0$ does $f'(0; u)$ exist? Evaluate it when it
exists.**

**(b) Do $D_1f$ and $D_2f$ exist at $0$?**

**(c) Is $f$ differentiable at $0$?**

**(d) Is $f$ continuous at $0$?**

I have thought a lot about this problem:

For (a), be $u\neq 0, u:=(h,k)$, so $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(th,tk)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(th)^3}{(th)^2+(tk)^2}\frac{1}{t}=\frac{h^3}{h^2+k^2}$, then $f'(0,u)$ exists for all $u\neq 0$.

For (b), $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+te_1)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(t,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^3}{t^3}=\lim_{t\to 0}1=1$ so $D_1f(0,0)=1$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+te_2)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}0=0$ so $D_2f(0,0)=0$

I am having problems solving (c) and (d), could someone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: What does $f'$ mean in this context (clearly, it cannot be the holomorphic derivative of $f$ because $f$ is not a holomorphic function)?  What are $D_1$ and $D_2$?  Is $D_1$ the differentiation with respect to the first variable (and the same applies to $D_2$)?

Comment: @Batominovski
$f'(0,u)$ is the directional derivative of $a$ with respect to the vector $u$ and $D_1$ and $D_2$ is what you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, $|x|\le \|(x,y)\|$ we have, $$|f(x,y)| =\frac{|x^3|}{x^2+y^2} =\frac{|x^3|}{\|(x,y)\|^2}\le \frac{\|(x,y)\|^3}{\|(x,y)\|^2}=\|(x,y)\|\to0$$

This prove the continuity of $f$.

**For the differentiability** we have $$\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}= \frac{h^3}{h^3} = 1$$
and 
$$\partial_x f(0,0)=\frac{f(h,h)-f(0,0)}{h}= \frac{h^3}{2h^3} = \frac{1}{2}$$
whereas
$$\partial_y f(0,0)=\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}= 0$$
Then f is not differentaible at (0,0).

> Indeed we have $\nabla f(0,0) = (1,0)$
>   But $$\lim_{(h, k)\to (0,0)} \frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)}{\|(h,k)\|}-\nabla f(0,0)\cdot (h,k)\neq 0$$
>   Because on the diagonal direction we have:
>   $$\lim_{(h, h)\to (0,0)} \frac{f(h,h)-f(0,0)}{\|(h,h)\|}-\nabla f(0,0)\cdot (h,h)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^3}{\sqrt{2}|h|h^2}-1\cdot h+0\cdot h) = ±\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \neq 0. $$

Comment: Why $\frac{|x^3|}{x^2+y^2}\le \|(x,y)\|$? $(\frac{|x^3|}{x^2+y^2}\leq |x|\leq \|(x,y)\|)$?

Comment: @user402543 see that $\|(x,y)\|^2=x^2+y^2$

Comment: Why $\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}= \frac{h^2}{h^2}$? $(\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}= \frac{h^3}{h^2}\frac{1}{h} =\frac{h^3}{h^3}=1)$?

Comment: $\|(x,y)\|=x^2+y^2$? It should not be $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: @user402543 any way I have put everything in now check aigain

Comment: Could you better clarify why $f$ is not differentiable in $(0,0)$? Thank you.

Comment: @user402543 I have added something in the body of the text for you

Answer (score 0):

Is my solution for (c) ok?

(c) Assume that $f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{0}$.
Let $\mathbf{u}=(1,1)$.
$f'(\mathbf{0};\mathbf{u})=Df(\mathbf{0})\cdot\mathbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix} D_1f(\mathbf{0})&D_2f(\mathbf{0})\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=1$.
On the other hand, from (a), $f'(\mathbf{0};\mathbf{u})=\frac{1}{2}$.
This is a contradiction.
So, $f$ is not differentiable at $\mathbf{0}$.

(d) Let $\mathbf{h}=(h_1,h_2)$.
$|f(h_1,h_2)-f(0,0)|=|\frac{h_1^3}{h_1^2+h_2^2}|\leq|h_1|\frac{|h_1^2|}{|h_1^2+h_2^2|}\leq|h_1|\frac{|h_1^2+h_2^2|}{|h_1^2+h_2^2|}\leq|h_1|\leq\max\{|h_1|,|h_2|\}=|\mathbf{h}|.$
So, $f$ is continuous at $\mathbf{0}$.